# How to use python to convert a Japanese PDF or HTML file into unicode

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to use python to read a Japanese PDF or HTML file as input, and I want to get each Japanese characters' unicode in the file.

Someone suggests that I can use 'tika' library to read a PDF file. I ran the following code and got a series of garbled text as below.

```
import tika
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('jpn.pdf')
print(parsed["content"])
```

result:

��������������������������������

�1948.12.10
������

����������������

�������������� �!"#$%&'()#�&*+,-.#/01�(

)#2345678(9:3;<=>$?�@A&B(�&3

�-�CD=>EFG3���HI/JK6LMNOPQR/SNTU3VW=>XY

�9:GZ8T[3]=>^_�+,45�`aG3Yc��d�ef�gh#U�

iVj[N�&3

�kGlm#no#6p�(eq�rs#U�tu6vw()#G+,xy6�(Nz

623{�|}6xM��-/~��()#G��&B(�&3

k��������/���()#G��&B(�&3

���67,�3@���-3�k�!"=>���>6��

��-6�,��X�/��1U3��3Y��*+9:�y�&���� #¡¢£

¤�¥¦#/���()#/§¨UN�&3

���#«¬U�3�-=>@��9:�­®�+!¯=>°±���/

²��()#/³´UN�&3

)[T�-.=>9:6p�(µ¶�·¸23)�³´/¹º6�(Nz6SM#S¯

�&B(�&3

���23 63

9Á�»¼�=>»½�G3)�45�-iV/¾6�¿6À*+GT3©ª

�ÃÄÅ6B(ÆÇ����k6S3)[T�-.#9:

#�!¯/ÈÉ=>ÊË6xM����()#�>6Ì[T�­®�ÍÀ6xM��~

#G²���*µ¶�@¤#U�����#����

�3)��-iV/ÏÐ�(Ñ

Is there any recommended Python library or code to deal with the aforesaid problem ?
This is my first time to ask question on this platform. Please help......

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using `tika-python` library ;
You can also try this code :

```
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('fileName.pdf')
print(parsed["metadata"])
print(parsed["content"])
```

Comment: These code can perfectly read English PDF files. Nevertheless, when I use the same code to process a Japanese PDF file, I only get a series of garbled text.

I do appreciate your effort, but I am still curious about how to retrieve the unicode of each character in  a PDF file.